# Classe Genérica recebendo uma Lista<genérica>?

Tags: c#, .net, genéricos

No c# tenho como implementar uma classe genérica onde 1 dos atributos recebidos é um objeto List<>? algo parecido com:

```
public class Negocio<TEnt, TDto, TDao, TList<coisas>>
```

De maneira que possa chamar ela desta forma...

```
Negocio<Entidade, Dto, Dao, TList<minhascoisas>> meunegocio = new Negocio<Entidade, Dto, Dao, TList<minhascoisas>>()
```

Estou tentando isso porque na verdade estou generalizando uma serie de classes com tudo semelhante, exceto por um conjunto de propriedades que pode variar inclusive em quantidade entre elas. Como não sei quantas propriedades serão (podem ser de zero a cinco) pensei em passa-las como uma list.

Isso possível? Alguém sabe dizer como? Tentei como nesse exemplo mas da erro de sintaxe.

Comment: Deve ter, mas precisamos de mais detalhes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem sim, é só usar `type parameter constraint`.
Coloquei `object` no tipo genérico da lista, altere para sua necessidade.

Exemplo:

```
public class Negocio<TEnt, TDto, TDao, TList>() where TList : IList<object>
{
}
```

Comment: Obrigado @MurariAlex ! Salvou minha vida, rsrsrs.